# Prevent Terminator from switching tab when opening another instance

Tags: terminator, shortcut-keys

I am using Terminator as default terminal emulator.  Every time I open another instance (e.g. via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) all already existing instances that have multiple tabs switch to the last tab (i.e. the rightmost one).

Why is this happening and what can I do to stop it from happening?

In case it matters: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: What is the command bound to your global keybinding? That may cause this behaviour. Please also describe more specifically what happens: "existing instance switches to the right": does that mean a new tab is opened to the left? Then you are opening both a new tab *and* a new window?

Comment: @vanadium Thanks to your comment I did some more tests and found out that it is not dependent on the keybinding (and also not on focus) but whenever I open another terminator instance, all existing instances switch tabs (assuming they have multiple tabs).  It does not open a new tab, just switches to the rightmost one in case there are multiple ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After narrowing down the problem and searching again with the new information, I found that this was [already reported](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/issues/99) and is fixed in recent versions of Terminator.

So the solution to solve this issue on Ubuntu 18.04 is to install the latest version from source instead of using the one that is provided via `apt-get`.